# SQL 2008 Find out what licensing it is using.

Tags: sql-server-2008

How can I tell the licensing that is setup on a production SQL server?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can you help me with my software licensing issue?](http://serverfault.com/questions/215405/can-you-help-me-with-my-software-licensing-issue)

Comment: This is going to get closed as a licensing issue.  It might be a better fit for dba.stackexchange.com, but check their FAQ first.

Comment: Its not a licensing issue really.

Comment: This is not a dupe. The s/w licencing question you reference is for *legal* issues with licences, not how to carry out licence related sysadmin tasks.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT CONVERT(char(20), SERVERPROPERTY('Edition'))
SELECT CONVERT(char(20), SERVERPROPERTY('NumLicenses'))
SELECT CONVERT(char(20), SERVERPROPERTY('LicenseType'))
```

PER_SEAT = Per-seat mode

PER_PROCESSOR = Per-processor mode

DISABLED = Licensing is disabled.

Comment: Please accept the answer if it was what you needed. Thanks. :)